# iframe not working with safari/firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I'm trying to figure out why my images aren't displaying properly within my iframe. Every browser works fine with the exception of Firefox and Safari. I can still click the links within the iframe and open up the corresponding page, but the images just won't display. I am using the instansive instagram widget as my iframe content (instansive.com). Their code looks like this - >

```
<!-- INSTANSIVE WIDGET --><script src="//instansive.com/widget/js/instansive.js"></script><iframe src="//instansive.com/widgets/427ad0d8ae95cfc36f19bb10c960dbf03bbef870.html" id="instansive_427ad0d8ae" name="instansive_427ad0d8ae"  scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true" class="instansive-widget" style="width: 100%; border: 0; overflow: hidden;"></iframe>
```

I'm not sure as to what I am doing wrong, or why it isn't displaying correctly with these two particular browsers.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to do with iframe. Try giving the image path as /test/image.jpg instead of full path. This may work